# Migrating from ExFAT to NTFS with Windows 7 running in Parallels upon a Mac OSX Yosimite 10.10.3

Tags: ntfs, windows-backup, exfat

If I use Windows 7 backup and restore util to backup an ExFAT external HDD. Then reformat the drive to NTFS , will I be able to restore the backed up files to the NTFS drive?